# How to access to some bytes of a file of bytearrays?

Tags: python, file

I have a text file that contains bytearray in each of its lines.
I want to print lines that their second and third number are equal to 34 and count them to show how many of the are existed in this file.
The content of my file.txt is:

```
12345678
12678364
90783457
95349387
```

The python script should print first and last line of this file.
To do this I write:

```
count =0
with open ('file.txt', 'rt') af in_file:
    for line in in_file:
        if line[2:4]=='34':  #problem is in this line. this line prints line numbers not value of each line.
            print("line: ", line)
            count +=1
        print("count: ", count)
```

I don't know how to write the `if` statement to work correctly.

Comment: There's a typo in your code, `with open('file.txt', 'rt') as in_file:`. And I've tested your example, the if condition is right. Maybe you should explain more about your question.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "`this line prints lines not value it it`"?